# $Variable not recognized as $null

Tags: variables, powershell, null, powershell-3.0

I have a SP list that I pull share point sites data from. If it is empty the variable still says it is not.

```
$SPSites = ($EmployeeAccItem.Fields["Sharepoint Site Membership"]).getfieldvalueastext($EmployeeAccItem["Sharepoint Site Membership"])

PS C:\Windows\system32> $SPSITES

PS C:\Windows\system32> $spsites.COUNT
1
PS C:\Windows\system32> test-path variable:\spsites
True
```

What is going on here? Is this white space? How can I make an if not `$null` statement?

I found this but I need the opposite to say if not null or white space then this.

```
IF([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($spsites))
```

Comment: Might have it.. (($SpAccess -eq "yes") -and ($SpSites -ne $spsites -ne [String]::Empty))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you use :

```
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($spsites))
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just went with the string method and also read about using $variable.length >0 is an option also.